# error reading in char in java

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner

```
char grid[][] = new char[size][size];
for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        grid[j][k] = in.next().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error in the in.next().charAt(0) line. I am tring to read in a grid that is made of chars. I don't truly understand how to read in chars, however I found that on another thread. Is there a reason that I cannot read in chars like this when reading in a grid? To visualize my input is as followed:

```
asdfv
sdsaf
asfdf
asfaf
asfdf
```

Also size is 5; Thank you in advance.

Comment: What type of an object is in?

Comment: "I'm getting an error" - so what's the error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using only the first character of each of your input lines.

For example, the first `in.next()` reads the "asdfv" `String`, but you only assign the first character of that `String` to your array and discard the rest.

You can change the code to:

```
char grid[][] = new char[size][size];
for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    grid[j] = in.nextLine().toCharArray();
}
```

This way `grid[j]` will be initialized with the characters of a full input line.